# Get sum from dynamic inputs vueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to calculate the total price of items using a checkbox for the product with the products price bound to the checkbox and the getting the total price from the number selected from another input. but this is not working as expected, since when I click the second product, it's price get's automatically calculated without me choosing the number of items I want. How can I fix this issue such that the total price is only calculated when a quantity is provided? Here is my code :

```
 const vm = new Vue ({
        el: "#app",
        data: {
            checkedValue: [],
            amount: [],
            items: [{name:"amazing", price:"2000"},
            {name:"kulahappy", price:"1000"},
            {name:"Yolo", price:"3000"}]
        },
        computed: {
            totalPrice (){
                const total = this.checkedvalue.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + parseInt(curr, 10), 0)
                const number = this.amount.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + parseInt(curr, 10), 0)
          const sum = total * number
          return sum
            }
        }
    })
```

The HTML

```
 <div id="app">
        <div v-for="(item, index) in items">
            {{item.name}}
            <input type="checkbox" :value="item.price" v-model="checkedValue" :key="index">
            <input type="number" v-model="amount[index]">

        </div>
        {{totalPrice}}
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi, The code is not attached

Comment: "the total price is only calculated when a quantity is provided"... So why not to abort calculating if there's no quantity value?

Comment: @TalGabay I just updated the   question with code

Comment: why are items in the cart just their prices? I think your approach to a shopping cart is a little convoluted, you're not getting any performance gains on doing it this way. I'd add a "quantity" property to each product object and bind it to the number of items, then I'd just loop over the items and sum their price times their quantity.

Comment: @fixmycode it's not really a shopping cart. and you should be able to choose the number of items you want, and they don't come with a  fixed quantity.